# Determinant of Laplacian removing $2$ (or more) rows and columns

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Based on [Kirchoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem), I'm wondering what can be said about the determinant of the Laplacian, after removing the columns and rows corresponding to two vertices. The motivation would be to see if iterating this process would give insight on the factorization or growth of the number of spanning trees as a function of the vertices.

I would appreciate any references to the literature! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Induction over the number of vertices whose corresponding rows and columns you are removing from the Laplacian matrix (hence removing those vertices from the graph): whatever is left from the original Laplacian matrix is guaranteed to be positive definite, if and only if at least one of the remaining vertices was connected to any of the vertices you removed.

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer? Just the simple case of a connected graph $G$ would be fine please. Only idea I can see - removing a single vertex (or a single row + column) results in a positive definite matrix (determinant is non zero due to Kirchhoff's theorem), but this does not mean the matrix is a Laplacian matrix, so I don't see how you can apply induction.

Comment: @Jake1234 Take your original Laplacian for a connected graph. Remove the row and column at index _i_. You end up with a positive definite matrix which looks like a smaller Laplacian (positive semi-definite) plus a zeroes-ones diagonal matrix (positive semi-definite). Now, remove the row and column at another index _j_. By Kirchhoff’s theorem, you are guaranteed that whatever remains from the smaller Laplacian is positive definite (hence, induction), and the zeroes-ones diagonal matrix may stay positive semi-definite or downgrade to null (iff it happened to have a singleton entry at index _j_).

Comment: @Jake1234 Given that the graph wasn’t disconnected after the removal of _i_ at the beginning of the second iteration.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: The submatrix of Laplacian after removing a row and column of some index, is not a Laplacian. The sum in rows/columns does not add to $1$ after removing a row/column, or replacing it with $0$ in non-diagonal indices, and $1$ on the diagonal.

Comment: @Jake1234 The submatrix of a Laplacian after removing a row and column of some index, is not a Laplacian, as the sum in some rows/columns does not add to *zero*
 after removing a row/column.

Comment: @Jake1234 Start with \begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\-1&2&-1\\&-1&2&-1\\&&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}
Remove first row and column: \begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\-1&2&-1\\&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}
which is equal to $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\-1&2&-1\\&-1&1 \end{bmatrix} +\begin{bmatrix} 1\\&0\\&&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ah, I get it, thank you.